# How to set Xcode up for LLVM/Clang development?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang, llvm

I've installed LLVM and Clang on macOS Sierra.

Until now, I've used the `llvm-config` command for compiling with `clang`. This works fine, and I can compile and link the LLVM tutorial programs from the command-line.

However, I'd like a professional IDE for development with type-checking and proper debugging.

The problem is that I don't know how to set Xcode up for LLVM/Clang development...

I include the C++ headers in the `include/llvm` directory, and I think I pass the libraries to the linker, but something goes wrong:

In the compilation phase, I get a linker error saying, e.g, that symbol `parseIRFile` isn't found. However, the IDE can see the functions in the header files.

Would someone help me out in setting up Xcode for LLVM/Clang development? I'm new to macOS and Xcode, so please give clear explanations of the required steps.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried to generate the Xcode project with cmake?

Comment: I did that when I build LLVM + Clang.

What do you mean?

Comment: Can you explain what you did first? Meanwhile, I can point to my old article on the topic: https://lowlevelbits.org/getting-started-with-llvm/clang-on-os-x/